# How to reduce repetition of prime factors of a number in this method

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I tried to solve Project Euler #3 as per the documented solution but it is resulting in repetition of prime factors.

[image]

In the above example for the factors of 10, 2 is repeating multiple time (3 times) where as 5 isn't repeating (I understood the reason behind it), but how to avoid it and print only factors of 10 just 2 and 5.

Comment: `n%f` is not valid R code, so I assume you are not using R?

Comment: Yes Richar Scriven, i'm using java script but added R to suggestion because of stack over flow suggestion's.

Comment: I don't understand these people who down vote questions because if they feel the question doesn't meet their standards please do answer it and then vote it down.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like the below

```
n = 10;
f = 2;
lf = 1;
on = n;
while(n>1) {
   if(n%f == 0) {  
     while(on%f == 0) {
         lf = f;
         n = n/f;
         console.log(lf);
         f=f+1;
     }   
  } else if (n<f) {
      n = 0;
  }
    else {
        f=f+1;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Sorry rajesh khannan, it solves my problemat the same time it is also resulting in an additional output of number '6' at the end.

Comment: here is the screenshot 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrjaxp0rw29xft0/Capture1.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Ok I got what is causing the problem. I just edited my answer above. Try now. I just removed `n=n/f ` outside of while loop. Give a try and let me know

Comment: Sorry @Rajeshkannan No use, It results in the same output as above screenshot displayed.

Comment: ok wait let me check it. Will post you once i get the correct logic

Comment: Hey Just now edited the code. GOT IT.. And It is **WORKING** Check now with the above code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution buddies.....

```
n = 10;
f = 2;
lf = 1;
while (n>1) {    
     if ( n%f ==0) {
          lf = f;
          n = n/f;
          while (n%f == 0) {
                 n = n/f;
          }
     console.log(f + "<br/>");
     }
     f = f + 1
}
```